# Django how are filter parameter names named?

Tags: python, django

I'm following the Django tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/. I've come across the **filter** and **get** functions. I'm confused as to why this is valid:

```
Question.objects.get(pub_date__year=current_year)
```

I understand that I defined pub_date in the Question model, but how did pub_date__year get created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, filter (and other Django and Python functions) can take any number of arbitrarily named keyword arguments, or kwargs, and Django simply parses these kwargs you pass.

Django defines this functionality in its [models.QuerySet object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter). You might also be interested in the [QuerySet source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L778).

See the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups), and the referenced Python documentation on this functionality [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Comment: @HudsonWorden Glad to help! Feel free to ask for clarifications or accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `pub_date` is an `DateField` or `DateTimeField` in the model so it is an instance of that class. Therefore it has a `year` attribute by default.

The reason you use the double underscore notation is because you can't have dotted notation in keyword arguments. So Django uses this double underscore as a way to compensate for this.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm confused how Django knows how to make pub_date__year reference pub_date.year if that makes sense.

Comment: pub_date is an argument name, not an object.

Comment: Which I pointed out by saying keyword arguments can't use dotted notation. In the OP's question it initially seemed like he didn't understand why `pub_date` had an attribute he didn't create. He clarified in his comment.